# Cannot Connect to Public RDS database

Tags: mysql, rds

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the images above, I have set my database to public access. Whenever I attempt to connect to it using the endpoint provided by RDS, it hangs up. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: How do you connect it?

Comment: @Smankusors I'm connecting to it using MYSQL Workbench, using the default port and inputing my username.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean "hangs up"? Is there any error messages? How about inbound rule?

Comment: Your connection attempt failed for user 'huntehhh' to the MySQL server at xx.xx.com

Please:
1 Check that MySQL is running on address xx.xx.com
2 Check that MySQL is reachable on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the user huntehhh has rights to connect to xx.xx.com from your address (MySQL rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for xx.xx.com connecting from the host address you're connecting from

Comment: I've included the error above ^

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you forgot about inbound rule. Here [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPCSecurityGroups) says

> When you create a security group, it has no inbound rules. Therefore,
>   no inbound traffic originating **from another host to your instance** is
>   allowed until you add inbound rules to the security group.

You only show the outbound rule, which I assume you are not setup the inbound rule. What that means that another computer cannot contact port 3306 of your RDS. But your RDS can connect to other computer with port 3306.